# Extract specific columns of CSV file into a python Array

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I need your help because I'm trying to extract 6 columns of a CSV which have 19 columns.

The CSV file is in the type for example :

```
,id,time,nodeaddr,appeui,gwaddr,modulation,datarate,snr,rssi,freq,lat,lon,alt,accuracy,hdop,sats,provider,user_agent

39634,223824,2016-02-13 00:00:00,0201010B,,0000B827EB0A3A3D,,,11.0,-63.0,,52.126919,5.043197,,,,,http://pade.nl/lora/coverage.json,

39636,223826,2016-02-13 00:00:00,0201010B,,0000B827EB0A3A3D,,,11.2,-73.0,,52.126373,5.043197,,,,,http://pade.nl/lora/coverage.json,

39637,223827,2016-02-13 00:00:00,0201010B,,0000B827EB0A3A3D,,,9.8,-97.0,,52.124901,5.040858,,,,,http://pade.nl/lora/coverage.json,

39639,223829,2016-02-13 00:00:00,0201010B,,0000B827EB0A3A3D,,,6.0,-99.0,,52.124237,5.039613,,,,,http://pade.nl/lora/coverage.json,
```

And I just want to extract the id, time, nodeaddr, rssi, lon and lat columns from that and make it into an array list which I can use on python

I have already seen some codes in there but I couldn't find one which is powerful with strings (because it's my problem here)

Thank you for your help !

zadss760

Comment: Hints: if you are a pandas fanatic, then `pd.read_csv` will do the job. If you are not the `csv` module will. Search for `csv.reader` or `csv.DictReader`... I am sorry, but SO is not intended to be a free code writing service. As a new user you should read [ask]. Here typically you have failed to show any research.

Comment: Maybe try https://github.com/DidierStevens/Beta/blob/master/csv-cut.py ?